# Save a version somewhere in GitHub

Tags: git, github

We have a GitHub project and a branch `dev`.

Several days ago, I cloned the `dev` branch, and made some local development in the folder `A` of my laptop. Yesterday, my developer made several commits to the same branch.

The last commit of my developer is good, so I will checkout it in another folder `B` of my laptop and continue from there. But I still want to save what is in `A` somewhere in the GitHub so that one day I may see the code.

Does anyone know what to do in this case? Do I have to create a new branch for that?

Comment: https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- you have a `dev` branch (Commit1)
- and you checked out in dir `A`
- other developer commits to `dev` (Commit2) and you want to keep this.

you should do this

- `cd A`
- `git checkout -b dev-version-a`
- `git push`
- `git checkout dev`
- `git pull`

now your dir A will have the updated code for dev branch
and you code which was earlier in dir A is pushed to git provide by branch name `dev-version-a`

Comment: is it possible to not create a new branch?

Comment: I guess after `git checkout -b dev-version-a` and before `git push`, we need to `git add .`.